# How do i publish in a callback function?

Tags: ros, callback, publisher, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening,

my problem is that i want to subscribe and publish in the same node. I need to publish in a callback function but the nodehandle is initialized in the `main()`. How can i publish a messages in  callback function? Is it possible to use a pointer to a publisher? If yes how could i do that?

Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224637/how-do-i-publish-in-a-callback-function?/) by [Gren8](https://answers.ros.org/users/25538/gren8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is easily possible and you should be able to find many examples of this in existing ROS packages. Some examples: [node (inside class)](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_lidar_proc/blob/master/vigir_lidar_intensity_modifier/src/laser_intensity_modifier_node.cpp#L52), [nodelet](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/image_proc/src/nodelets/rectify.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1